# "cannot be assigned to -- it is read only" error on ConditionExpression

Tags: c#, .net, dynamics-crm-2011, xrm

I have to create "between date" condition.

When I write like this:

```
ConditionExpression modifiedOnCondition = new ConditionExpression();
modifiedOnCondition.AttributeName = "modifiedon";
modifiedOnCondition.Operator = ConditionOperator.Between;
modifiedOnCondition.Values = new Object[] { startDate, endDate };
```

`startDate` and `endDate` are `DateTime`. I got an error on `modifiedOnCondition.Values`. It says:

> Property or indexer 'Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Query.ConditionExpression.Values' cannot be assigned to -- it is read only

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't change `Values` property after object has been created, just pass it as parameter in `ConditionExpression` constructor:

```
var modifiedOnCondition = new ConditionExpression(
    "modifiedon",
    ConditionOperator.Between,
    new Object[] { startDate, endDate });
```